# How to minify internal css in NuxtJs?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxtjs

I have included css files in to nuxtJs config file,
so i want to minify them but i do not want to extract them to external css file.

Is there any way of doing this?.

#### Code

```
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/tailwind.css",
    "~/assets/scss/styles.scss",
    "~/static/js/plugins/slick/slick.css",
    "~/static/js/plugins/fotorama/fotorama.css",
    "swiper/dist/css/swiper.css"
  ],
  build: {
    extractCSS: false,
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/guides/nuxt.html#nuxt-js-plugin) and the [module for NuxtJS](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-purgecss)